# How to erase a stroke in canvas with globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out'?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to erase a stroke in a canvas by using the [CanvasRenderingContext2D.globalCompositeOperation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) property of the Canvas 2D API but it doesn't work.

Here is what I've tested : [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Souhail_5/pen/VBNYmv)

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.save();

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";

ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.restore();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

(The stroke disappear only if I multiply the second `ctx.stroke();` several times).

**Can you help me to get it work OR achieve my initial goal?**

- Context:

  - I have some "shapes" within a javascript object
  - These "shapes" are drawn in the canvas
- my goal is to hide/show a shape as soon as added/deleted in the javascript object

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Compositing works with the alpha channels. The line you are drawing is not on pixel bounds and gets antialiased. If you check the pixel alpha values you'll see they're not opaque. So gCO will not work as you ontended here. You could make the lineWidth bigger in the second call to circumvent it though it will also bleed outside of the stroke...

Comment: Have you considered using SVG graphics? Each shape you and can then be an element, and you can cleanly and completely remove shapes by deleting their corresponding elements.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately I can’t opt for your solution if it bleed outside of the stroke.

Comment: @kshetline yes I will use SVG if no other solution. For now I have an app that works with canvas but doesn’t implement the erasing feature ; and I don’t want to make lot of change to it.

Comment: But what is it exactly you want to do? A stroke of transparent pixels? Or just remove that line from your drawings? If the later, clear everything and redraw everything, everytime. Otherwise, svg won't help you either as it will suffer from the same restrictions.

Comment: @Kaiido I want to remove the line or make it invisible (on a transparent background). This was my first intuition but I can have lot of "shapes" (within my javascript objects), so I am afraid that it will be very slow to clear everything and redraw everything, every time I decide to **hide/show** a draw. I've edited my question to clarify that.

Comment: Clearing + redrawing is fast, as long as you don't have 10k+ shapes to draw every 16th of seconds you'll be fine and if ever you do have to do it, there are ways to do it too.

Comment: The best way to achieve decent results though is not to draw them every time, but to buffer your shapes in separate canvas elements that can just be drawn at `xy` coordinates, which will speed up your drawing significantly. So if you have a line in a 200x200 canvas`, draw it in one and then draw that layer.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido. I do it this way and hope it will be good.

Comment: @somethinghere It's a nice idea but I would prefer to use SVG than several canvas into the DOM. And keeping one canvas for drawing.

Comment: You do not place the multiply `canvas` in the dom, you draw them into one canvas and add that. The others are simply pixel-data buffers, arrays of values that just contain colors. At that point you can start using composite operations etc easily (where <svg> will have trouble doing some calculations on this). Anyway it's just a suggestion, but if you are interested in efficient drawing, then using `canvas` as buffers is the way to go.

Comment: @somethinghere Thanks for the clarification. Can you make a short POC in CodePen (or similar) ? This can help a lot.

Comment: @Souhail_5 I have added an answer with a sort-of exmaple on how this works. But its nothing more than drawing your layers separately, and then combining them all into one output canvas. A canvas has a 2D buffer in the background, so using that data inside another canvas is rather fast. It's basically what you computer does the whole time - compositing images. Anyway, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At request, here is an example of drawing with layers of `canvas` as buffers. Basically, you can draw on every layer with a random color and they will be drawn into the central canvas, you can check the layers on and off to see whats going on. Hope it helps.

```js
var layers = document.getElementById( 'layers' );
var output = document.querySelector( '#output canvas' );
var add = document.getElementById( 'add' );
var id = 0;
var selected;

add.addEventListener( 'click', event => {
  
  event.preventDefault();
  
  let li = document.createElement( 'li' );
  let canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );;
  let checkbox = document.createElement( 'input' );
  
  checkbox.checked = true;
  checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
  checkbox.addEventListener( 'change', event => {
    
    li.classList.toggle( 'visible' );
    
  });
  
  li.canvas = canvas;
  li.textContent = 'Layer #' + (++id);
  li.classList.add( 'visible' );
  li.addEventListener( 'click', event => {
    
    layers.querySelectorAll( '.selected' ).forEach(child => {
      child.classList.remove( 'selected' );
    });
    li.classList.add( 'selected' );
    selected = li.canvas;
    
  });
  li.insertBefore( checkbox, li.childNodes[ 0 ] );
  
  layers.appendChild( li );
  
});

var color;

output.addEventListener( 'mousedown', event => {
  
  let r = Math.floor( Math.random() * 255 );
  let g = Math.floor( Math.random() * 255 );
  let b = Math.floor( Math.random() * 255 );
  
  color = `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;
  
});
output.addEventListener( 'mouseup', event => {
  
  color = null;
  
});
output.addEventListener( 'mousemove', event => {
  
  if( color && selected ){
    
    let ctx = selected.getContext( '2d' );

    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect( event.offsetX - 5, event.offsetY - 5, 10, 10 );

  }
  
});

function draw(){

  let ctx = output.getContext( '2d' );
  output.width = output.width;
  output.height = output.height;
  
  [ ...layers.childNodes ].forEach(child => {
    
    if( child.tagName && child.classList.contains( 'visible' ) ){
    
      ctx.drawImage( child.canvas, 0, 0, child.canvas.width, child.canvas.height );
      
    }
    
  })
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame( draw );
  
}

draw();
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
#layers {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #666;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#layers li {
  color: white;
}
#layers li.selected {
  background: rgba( 255,255,255,.5);
  color: black;
 }

#output {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: #ececec;
}
#output canvas {
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px #888;
}
```

```html
<ul id="layers">
  <li id="add">Add Layer</li>
</ul>
<div id="output">
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```